# Algorithm - how to detect stable falling on noisy data?

Tags: algorithm, charts, detection, data-analysis

So I have a lot of charts that look like this:

[image: charts]

They all follow the same basic process: more or less horizontal slope in the beginning with a lot of noise (but usually already falling), then the inflection point and more rapid falling (less noisy, but still noisy) followed by smooth horizontal slope. I need to find a way to detect that inflection point. As you can see, the charts at the top are falling REALLY slowly as opposed to those at the bottom. This is a problem for me, as all methods I've tried (smoothing and then calculating derivatives, trend lines and calculating angle for the line, MSE thresholds, CUSUM) work well for rapid falling, but fail to catch slow falling (or give false positives).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try a Savitsky-Golay second derivative filter and consider the last negative value.

Be prepared to uncorrectable cases. For example, with your dark blue curve, I couldn't tell which inflection to choose.

Comment: I want to clarify: I need to apply Savitsky-Golay filter to smooth the data and _then_ take the second derivative? Otherwise I don't understand what "second derivative filter" means. What is the benefit of choosing this filter over others?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I see the part about calculating the derivatives now. So I tried that in Excel using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter#Appendix) formula. And the result is weird and all over the place, probably I'm doing something wrong. [Here's](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LaHiv1ufL2KZsCPdYZ9_eN6k133qwlX-/view?usp=sharing) the Excel file with data and calculated values for the second derivative. _h_ is 0.1 in my case

Comment: [Here](https://imgur.com/a/3dsa0). It's a mess to look at. I applied the formula from the Wiki to the original data, this is what I got. The first picture is all 9 columns plotted, the second one is just the first column.

Comment: @graynk: this doesn't look right. Of course you expect a noisy signal, but here you don't even distinguish different regimes. Can you show the first derivative ?

Comment: it kinda looks the same as the second. Smoothing using formula from the same paragraph looks normal though. [Link](https://imgur.com/a/srpXd)